# How to pick variables from a Sub Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My Initial query is something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dbo.customerdetails 
  WHERE customername LIKE ('rit%' ) 
     OR customername LIKE ('mic%')
```

I have two variables, i.e. variable1 and variable2.

I'd like to import `rit` and `mic` into these variables where I can reuse these variables in another query as like statement.
The initial query variables are fed from front end.The should be picked up but latter query also.

Comment: Please format non-inline chunks of code with four spaces in front, rather than enclosing them in `\``.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the two variables and initialize the variables with the `rit` and `mic`.  Try this.

```
Declare @variable1 varchar(50)='rit',
        @variable2 varchar(50)='mic'

SELECT * 
  FROM dbo.customerdetails 
  WHERE customername LIKE @variable1+'%' 
     OR customername LIKE @variable2+'%'
```

Comment: sorry if my question was not very clear. the initial query variables are fed from front end.The should be picked up but latter query also.